# Reset timer when using prev next button on a slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have a slideshow of images,that it changes automatically( autoslide() ) every 5 sec, so when i press one of the next/back buttons, the countdown continues.

How I want to behaves : When one of the next/back buttons is pressed, the autoslide function countdown starts over from 0 seconds, without continuing the previous countdown.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $prev = $('.previousx');
  var $next = $('.nextx');
  var mode = "auto";
  $prev.on({
    click: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mode = "auto";
      showPreviousImage();
    }
  });
  $next.on({
    click: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mode = "auto";
      showNextImage();
      
    }
  });
  
  setInterval(function(){
    if(mode==="auto"){
      showNextImage();
    }
  },5000);
  
  
  
  function showNextImage(){
      var $actEl = $('.activx');
      var $nextEl = $actEl.next('.slidex');
      if($nextEl.length){
        $actEl.removeClass('activx');
        $nextEl.addClass('activx');
      }else{
        $actEl.removeClass('activx');
        $('.slidex:first-child').addClass('activx');
      }
  }
  
  function showPreviousImage(){
      var $actEl = $('.activx');
      var $prevEl = $actEl.prev('.slidex');
      if($prevEl.length){
        $actEl.removeClass('activx');
        $prevEl.addClass('activx');
      }else{
        $actEl.removeClass('activx');
        $('.slidex.last').addClass('activx');
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Save your `setInterval` in a variable and on button click reset interval using `clearInterval`. And re-assign the variable with new setInterval

Maybe try this.

```js
const autoChange = () => {
   if(mode==="auto"){
      showNextImage();
    }
}

let interval = setInterval(autoChange,5000);

$next.on({
    click: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mode = "auto";
      showNextImage();
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = setInterval(autoChange,5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to do this

Comment: I've added code in the answer, try it.

Comment: good working thank you